# Set order of extensions/indicators in gnome 3

Tags: gnome, panel

Is it possible to set the order in which extensions/indicators appear in the top panel in gnome 3 as they seem to change position every time I login and I want to set a specific order.

Comment: Which GNOME version?

Comment: @A.B. 3.14 I think, the default that comes with 15.04

Comment: Ok, here is your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR** The way is a little bit tricky:

You can reload and so influence the order the extensions.

Use this command and replace `<Extension_UUID>` with the `UUID` of the extension, **don't** use the `ID`:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method <Extension_UUID>
```

*But I have found that sometimes the extension must be reloaded twice to achieve an effect.*

---

Example:

My system wide extensions:

```
% ls -og  /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 4096 Mär 31 15:15 GPaste@gnome-shell-extensions.gnome.org
```

My per user extensions:

```
% ls -og ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 3 4096 Mär 26 08:01 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 3 4096 Mär 26 08:02 laine@knasher.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x 4 4096 Mär 26 07:56 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x 3 4096 Mär 26 07:57 web_search_dialog@awamper.gmail.com
```

The extension ID should be the folder name, eg. `drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com`.

To be sure, I would pick up the `UUID` from the metadata file:

```
% less ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/metadata.json
{
  "_generated": "Generated by SweetTooth, do not edit", 
  "description": "A status menu for accessing and unmounting removable devices.", 
  "extension-id": "drive-menu", 
  "gettext-domain": "gnome-shell-extensions", 
  "name": "Removable Drive Menu", 
  "settings-schema": "org.gnome.shell.extensions.drive-menu", 
  "shell-version": [
    "3.16"
  ], 
  "url": "http://git.gnome.org/gnome-shell-extensions", 
  "uuid": "drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com", 
  "version": 28
}
```

Therefore this is the command to reload the extension

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.ReloadExtension "drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com"
```

---

The UUID can be determined reliably with the following commands:

Install a JSON parser:

```
sudo apt-get install jq
```

Determine the UUID with:

```
jq '.uuid' ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/<shell_extension_path>/metadata.json
```

Example:

```
% jq '.uuid' ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/metadata.json
"drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com"
```

Or all in one:

```
gdbus call --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Shell --method org.gnome.Shell.Extensions.ReloadExtension  $(jq '.uuid' ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/metadata.json)
```

---

### An other great solution is [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/661015/367165).

Comment: Thank you this works. So if I write a script that runs at startup and reloads them in a specific order I can get them to display in the order I want.

Comment: Yes, that right.

Comment: No longer works in modern versions, but a simple equivalent is `gnome-extensions disable <EXT_ID>; gnome-extensions enable <EXT_ID>`
The extension ID can be obtained the same way without issue.