# Ubuntu 20.04 keeps showing a power plug icon

Tags: icons, power-management, 20.04, gnome-shell, indicator

Why does Ubuntu keep showing this icon?
[image]

Info:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- GNOME
- dash-to-panel used

Comment: Apparently, this has nothing to do with the Dell Dock.
I have removed all peripherals, rebooted. And the problem is solved!

Comment: Could you please expand your comment to an answer (e.g. how to remove all peripherals, which command(s), if any, to run etc.) and post to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239006/what-does-the-indicator-icon-with-three-dots-over-a-power-plug-mean-in-ubuntu-20) to help future readers. Thanks.