# Can we in any way drag and drop the extensions icon/symbol to change their positions. How we can control it easily in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: titlebar, extension

Can we in anyway drag and drop extensions icons by mouse click in the title bar? How can we control its placement w.r.t to others easily?

[image]

In this picture such a feature is required. It will make it easier still for the user. If it is already there I do not know, would be happy if anyone can show me how to do this. Thank you!

P.S. (It would be good if someone with higher credits can edit this question with tags placement positioning. Thanks.)

Comment: You should specify a Desktop Environment in your question. Different DEs have different design philosophies.

Comment: Ubuntu. Yes it is there in question. Thanks. Is it possible to drag and drop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I order Gnome3 shell extensions at the top?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453969/how-can-i-order-gnome3-shell-extensions-at-the-top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you probably experienced yourself, no, you cannot drag and drop to change the order by which extensions are displayed in the top bar. In addition, it is not trivial to control the order extensions load and in which they are displayed. The latter is also the topic of [a previously asked question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453969/how-can-i-order-gnome3-shell-extensions-at-the-top).

Comment: I hope there comes and easier way like drag and drop for common users. It is there for plank and dock, so it must come for the tiny looking but extremely useful extensions. Some good coder must do the change. Thanks for pointing the similar question. I read those but it does not answer the question but your answer does. You seem confident that it cannot be done so I am accepting this answer now. Hope you are right. :)